# Moving between Storyboard scenes - Segues and Unwind

Tags: ios, interface-builder, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I hope this makes sense and hopefully you can see in the picture the buttons in the top right of each scene to move to the others.
So far I can move from "Sine Wave" to "Saw Wave" with a modal segue, back to "Sine Wave" with an unwind, but what I need to be able to do is move back to "Saw Wave" again without calling a new instance of it.
Is this possible, and if so, how?
http://i50.tinypic.com/17bx1l.png

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can do this, but not with a segue, since segues alway create new view controllers (other than unwind segues). So, you need to present "Saw Wave" in code like this (from "Sine Wave"):

```
-(IBAction)goToSawWave:(UIButton *) sender {
    if (! self.sawWave) self.sawWave = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SawWave"];
    [self presentViewController:sawWave animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

sawWave is a property typed to the class SawWave, you should change this to whatever the real class name is, and make sure you set the identifier for this controller in IB. Because you create a strong reference to your instance of SawWave, and check for its existence before presenting it, you will go to the same instance.

Comment: Thank you very much @rdelmar
This is almost perfect, except I'd need to be able to have things like the sliders and toggles (seen in the linked picture from the OP) to be in the same position when I move to and from each scene.
I managed to partially achieve this with segue unwind but not entirely.
Thanks again.

Comment: In other words is there a way of preventing them from being reset when transitioning between scenes?

Comment: @amk1, yes, if you do it the way I showed, everything should be the same in "Saw Wave" when you come and go, and doing an unwind from "Saw Wave" should come back to "Sine Wave" as it was when you left it. Are you not seeing this?